# MySQL order-by original "where order"

Tags: php, mysql, sql-order-by

I have this order-by problem I canot crack. I select from my table like this:

```
SELECT * FROM 'sidemodules' WHERE name = 'module1' OR name = 'module2' OR 'name3'
```

Which returns me the modules I want. But the modules lie the table, say in this order:

1. Module3
2. Module1
3. Module2

And they are returned to me in this order. How can I get them to display in order AS IN THE `WHERE` CLAUSE (1,2,3)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're looking for [`FIELD`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/string-functions.html#function_field):

```
SELECT * FROM sidemodules
WHERE name IN ('module1', 'module2', 'name3')
ORDER BY FIELD(name, 'module1', 'module2', 'name3')
```

Anyway, if the names are in alphabetic order just use:

```
ORDER BY name
```

Also note that using the `IN` operator is usually faster than just using many `OR`s.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it was most useful! The Codigniter implementation if anyone is interested, can be found here: [link](http://www.simonemms.com/2011/04/07/codeigniter-activerecord-order-by-field/)

Answer (score 1):

you need to use FIELD in order by clause. returnset will the same order you write.

```
SELECT * FROM sidemodules
WHERE name IN ('module1', 'module2', 'name3')
ORDER BY FIELD(name, 'module1', 'module2', 'name3')
```

result:
module1, module2, name3

```
SELECT * FROM sidemodules
WHERE name IN ('module1', 'module2', 'name3')
ORDER BY FIELD(name, 'module2', 'module1', 'name3')
```

result:
module2, module1, name3

Answer (score 0):

I think you have a typo in your question. Your last condition should be `name = 'module3'` instead of just `name3`

Please try the following:

```
SELECT * 
FROM 'sidemodules' 
WHERE name = 'module1' OR name = 'module2' OR name = 'module3'
ORDER BY name;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a fixed order you can order with a CASE statement:

```
SELECT * FROM 'sidemodules' 
WHERE name = 'module1' 
  OR name = 'module2' 
  OR name = 'module3'
ORDER BY CASE
  WHEN name = 'module1' THEN 1
  WHEN name = 'module3' THEN 2
  WHEN name = 'module2' THEN 3
 ELSE '0'
END
```